# ruby on rails chaining 3 actions from one button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller, method-chaining

I have a controller with new, create, and edit actions, amongst others as shown below.
Right now, I have 3 buttons in my form, one to start a new project (new), another button to save it (create) and a 3rd button to edit the project after it is created (edit).

I'd like to create a single button that would combine the execution of all 3 actions in sequence : new, then create, then edit.

Is that possible?

```
# GET /projects/new
# GET /projects/new.json
def new
  @project = Project.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @project }
  end
end

# GET /projects/1/edit
def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /projects
# POST /projects.json
def create
  @project = Project.new(params[:project])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to @project, :notice => 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :json => @project, :status => :created, :location => @project }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: After saving the project (`POST` to `create`) you want the user to see the edit form?

Comment: @Jared : thanks for your prompt response. YES, I want the use to see the edit form when they create a new project.

Comment: OK.  Try Aalaa Mohamed's answer (redirect to `edit`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create
 @project = Project.new(params[:project])

 respond_to do |format|
  if @project.save
   format.html { redirect_to edit_project_path(@project), :notice => 'Project was successfully created.' }
   format.json { render :json => @project, :status => :created, :location => @project }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: This meets the OP's requirements, but I dislike `before_action` callbacks and would put the redirect in the `#create`, perhaps a matter of personal style.

Comment: @AalaaMohamed : thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it worked fine for chaining "create" and "edit" but it did not work for chaining "new" and "create". My goal is to chain all 3 at the same time.

Comment: When you click on your new project button it will redirect you to the new form and then the project will be created and then you will be redirected to edit, Is that what you meant by chaining the three actions ?

Comment: if you are using rails plz follow Restful approach. CURD has its meaning don't pollute your application.

Comment: @AalaaMohamed : yes, I want the user to click the button once, and all 3 actions will be executed in sequence

Comment: @rh4games that's my best, maybe i don't understand your question.

Comment: @lokeshjain2008 : I think you're right. I'm probably not using the right tool to do what I want to do. What does not work for me in this model is that I need 3 actions to be able to edit my form (new, then create, then edit). I need a project ID to start editing the form, but "new" action does not provide that ID, until I "create" the project. I'm looking for a shortcut to this process.